# Input Text FROM Console .py

Tags: python

Im trying to take the console output and use that data to send it as a message in my discord bot.

```
bot.on('kicked', console.log)
bot.on('error', console.log)
```

so the output is reaching the console but I want to use that code to send the message

```
if message.content.startswith('$log in'):
    os.system('node bot.js')
    await message.channel.send('')
```

what can I enter in the await string to make it use the console output from the other code?
is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to log and inspect the messages, instead of passing directly to `console.log` you could pass it to a function which does the check, and also logs the message as well.